# Google API redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, credentials

just installed a plug in to save me time in uploading many images from my google drive to a a new client's website. It has installed correctly and I have created an API in console for this and it still flags this issue below.

I have added -

- API keys
- OAuth 2.0 Client IDs
  and
- Service Accounts

In Google Cloud Platform I just need to link Google drive to the Wordpress media plug in on website.

Screenshot

[image]

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request, http://studiotwo-co-uk.stackstaging.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number} to update the authorized JavaScript origins.
```

Answer (score -1):

As the message states you need to go to google developer console for your project and under the JavaScript origin section you should add

> http://studiotwo-co-uk.stackstaging.com

Without it your application wont work it needs to know where the code is running from.

I have a video which explains this error and how to fix it. [Google Oauth: error redirect_uri_mismatch the javascript origin Quick Fix.](https://youtu.be/V0-4LnHwFho)